# When I deploy my version of my website on gh-pages branch, there are no new commits added

Tags: deployment, github-pages

When I deploy my version of the website on gh-pages branch, there are no new commits added, I know there was a script for clearing the branch before deploying but I don't remember it. It even was an answer here on stackoverflow, does anybody know a solution? I tried to delete the branch but the commits won't go away.

Comment: UPDATE: I just renamed the gh-pages branch from remote in something else, and then deployed the gh-pages branch again and it worked